NFS V4.2 - Slow localhost ramdisk export
I have a Dell R720 with a Xeon(R) CPU E5-2680 v2 and 1333 MHz DDR3 RAM. I'm hosting a VM with KVM under Proxmox which plays the role of a NFS server. It's running Arch Linux with Kernel Linux StorageVM 6.9.7-arch1-1 #1 SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Fri, 28 Jun 2024 04:32:50 +0000 x86_64 GNU/Linux.
The server is supposed to eventually share it's storage with other clients. For now, a tmpfs filesystem is mounted at /mnt/tmp and expoted using nfsv4-server as such:

/mnt/tmp *(rw,sync,no_root_squash,no_subtree_check)

The same virtual server mounts it's own share at /nfsdata as such:

mount -t nfs 127.0.0.1:/mnt/tmp /nfsdata -o nfsvers=4.2,sync,nolock,proto=tcp,noacl,rsize=$((1024*1024)),wsize=$((1024*1024))

Writing to this mounted share with dd if=/dev/urandom of=/nfsdata/test bs=1M status=progress oflag=direct results in abysmal speeds of around 100 MB/s. Actual generation speed is around 300-400 MB/s.
The IOPS tested with fio are also terrible, results are around 2000 (for a ramdisk!). They're tested with:

fio --filename=/nfsdata/test.file -name=sync_randwrite --rw=randwrite --bs=4k --direct=1 --sync=1 --numjobs=1 --ioengine=psync --iodepth=1 --refill_buffers --size=1G --loops=1 --group_reporting

The CPU is barely sweating, as the machine has 16 vCores allocated to it, and is NUMA aware with no interleave hits or misses.
The same behavior also happens on another machine with an i5-5350U with 1600 MHz DDR3 RAM running on bare-metal, but the IOPS are much more reasonable, around 14K with the exact same settings.
What could be the cause of this? Is NFSv4 itself the problem here, or could it be related to the system?
EDIT: The read performance seems to be fine, it is just writes that are this slow. I realize that I use sync options, but those should be at least meaningless considering the fact that it's all localhost, and the storage medium is actually a ramdisk.
EDIT: The sequential read speeds for a 10 GB file is 4.7 GB/s directly from the ramdisk (with dd bs=1M), but only 0.85 GB/s through NFS mounted in the same way.

It looks like this is one of a kind issue, which was actually caused by a kernel bug, where VirtIO interfaces were bridged using Linux Bridges on the host.
More details here: https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=219129
